# Purpose of JDialog#setModal

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

What is the purpose of `d.setModal(true);`?

```
public DatePicker(JFrame parent) {
    dialog = new JDialog();
    dialog.setModal(true);

    String[] header = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 7));
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(430, 120));

    ...
}
```

I have tried to search here, on StackOverflow, but did not find any convincing answer.

Comment: graphical control element subordinate to an application's main window.

Comment: Modal window grants that only this window may have focus (if it displayed).

Comment: Down-voted because lack of research. This question can simply be answered by reading the official documentation of the method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good idea to check the main documentation: [setModal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModal(boolean))

> modal - specifies whether dialog blocks input to other windows when shown;

Also note that

> This method is obsolete and is kept for backwards compatibility only. Use `setModalityType()` instead.

Then check the [Dialog.ModalityType](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) to see what your options are.